# JS function not working in Django template

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates

template:

```
{% extends 'home.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Customer{% endblock %}
<script src="{% static 'js/sign_up.js' %}"></script>

{% block content %}
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        Date of Birth:(dd/mm/yyyy)
        <label>
            <select id="day">
                <option value="1" onclick="day()">1</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label>
            <select id="month">
                <option value="1" onclick="month()">1</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label>
            <select id="year">
                <option value="1" onclick="year(">1</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

JS file

```
function day() {
    let dd = 1;
    for (dd = 1; dd <= 31; dd++) {
        document.getElementById("day")
        document.write("<option value=" + dd + ">" + dd + "</option>")
    }
}

function month() {
    let mm = 1;
    for (mm = 1; mm <= 12; mm++) {
        document.getElementById("month")
        document.write("<option value=" + mm + ">" + mm + "</option>")
    }
}

function year() {
    let yy = 1950;
    for (yy = 1950; yy <= 2020; yy++) {
        document.getElementById("year")
        document.write("<option value=" + mm + ">" + mm + "</option>")
    }}
```

js function is not working i can't understand what happened i create separate file where i declare functions for date of birth form but it's not response any thing except the html

Comment: Do you import the JS file in the html template?

Comment: yes i import even in base.html and also in customer template

Comment: Do yo see any error messages in browser console or 404/403 and so on in "network" tab of browser devtools?

Comment: DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/bootstrap.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Comment: how to fix tell me

Comment: Try to grab your js file url from rendered page and open it manually - is the browser able to load it?